# How to update TexWorks on Debian 6 Synaptic/apt-get

Tags: installing, texworks

Synaptic has only version 2.3 listed.

I want the latest version 4.0.

I want to avoid manual compilation, dependency hell, all that.

How do I update to version 4.0?

Thanks.

```
peter@debian-peter:~$ sudo apt-get install texworks
[sudo] password for peter: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texworks is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  liburiparser1 libcurl3 libssh2-1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
N: Ignoring file 'apt-build' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
peter@debian-peter:~$ apt-build install texworks
Package texworks already in repository.
-----> Updating package lists <-----
N: Ignoring file 'apt-build' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
peter@debian-peter:~$ sudo apt-build install texworks
Package texworks already in repository.
-----> Updating package lists <-----
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.0 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20110205-17:27] squeeze Release.gpg
Ign file: apt-build Release.gpg
Ign file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository/ apt-build/main Translation-en        
Ign file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository/ apt-build/main Translation-en_AU     
Get:1 file: apt-build Release [89 B]                                           
Ign file: apt-build/main i386 Packages                                         
Ign file: apt-build/main i386 Packages                                         
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg                     
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en            
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_AU         
Hit http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze Release.gpg                               
Ign http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en               
Ign http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en_AU      
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release                   
Hit http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze-updates Release.gpg                       
Ign http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en       
Ign http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en_AU
Hit http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze Release                                   
Hit http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze-updates Release                           
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main Sources                    
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze/main Sources                              
Hit http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze/main i386 Packages                  
Hit http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.debian.org sid Release.gpg          
Hit http://ftp.debian.org sid Release              
Hit http://ftp.debian.org sid/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.0 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20110205-17:27]/ squeeze/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.0 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20110205-17:27]/ squeeze/main Translation-en_AU
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.0 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20110205-17:27] squeeze Release
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.0 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20110205-17:27] squeeze/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file 'apt-build' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texworks is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  liburiparser1 libcurl3 libssh2-1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
N: Ignoring file 'apt-build' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
```

Comment: Is 'download the source' an acceptable answer? Building on Ubuntu is easy, so it should not be significantly different on Debian.

Comment: If things go wrong, or I change my mind later, how can I do a clean install?  I don't remember the paths where everything's gone to, and I'm hesitant to install anything I can't cleanly reverse...  If you can teach me how to do a clean install, I'll do it that way. :)

Comment: In the past my filesystem was strewn with broken installs because I tried and failed compiling programs all over the place and had no idea or way of cleanly reversing failed installs. :|

Comment: I think this question belongs more on superuser than tex.se.

Comment: Latexmk for bibliography  compile (runs twice automatically as needed).

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

Debian sid has version `0.5~svn808-1`. You can build and install it like this:

Add the sources for sid packages to your sources.list:

```
# echo "deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Install apt-build:

```
# apt-get install apt-build
```

Build and install texworks:

```
# apt-build install texworks
```

Otherwise, you could also download the source and use `checkinstall` to generate a Debian package. The `apt-build` method is cleaner if it works, because it uses the official Debian packages.

Comment: I don't think it worked; see OP.  The version on my Desktop is unchanged from 2.3...

Comment: I added the source and installed apt-build correctly.  It's the third step I'm concerned hasn't been executed correctly...  Shouldn't the new version override my old one?  If not, then from where and how do I launch the new version?  TY

Comment: You need to be root to use `apt-build install`. Use `sudo` in front of the command.

Comment: See OP for output - I think it's clearly doing something, just not sure if it succeeded because my texworks version hasn't changed following the install.

Comment: What I see are `permission denied` errors, which means you need to run it as root.

Comment: I used sudo, isn't that the right way to do it?  Is this last line relevant to the problem:  N: Ignoring file 'apt-build' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension?

Comment: Try with `sudo apt-build install texworks=0.5.*` to force the version from sid.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try your luck installing the Ubuntu packages from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~texworks/+archive/stable). They do not have any Ubuntu-specific files so I suspect they will work just fine.

If you have older Qt version, you can try some of the packages for older Ubuntu releases (`natty` requires Qt 4.7, while for `hardy` the minimum version is only Qt 4.3.4). The rest of the dependencies (`libc`, `gcc`, `hunspell`, `poppler`, `zlib`) should be easy to satisfy, and you probably have them already installed.